# How to get True/False value in a cell based on other cell's value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a drop-down list in A1 with "Y" and "N". I want to write a code in cell B1 to get value "True" if A1 is "Y" and "False" if A1 is "N".

```
Sub YCheck()

Dim CellCheck As Boolean

Set Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = CellCheck

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Y Then
CellCheck = True

ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = N Then
CellCheck = False

End If
End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to work. Anyone could help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply `CellCheck = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Y")`? Explicitly assigning `True` based on a Boolean condition is somewhat redundant.

Comment: a simple worksheet formula will do the same: `=A1="Y"`

Comment: @ScottCraner: That is the answer! why go VBA if it can be done natively? Introducing VBA means macro-enabled workbooks (could be extra work depending on organisational trust settings), extra things to go wrong and simple steps that are hidden from the uninitiated.

Answer (score 2):

Y and N should have quotes around them for starters. I'm assuming they aren't intended to be undefined variables... The line where you set B1 should be at the end, not the beginning, and you shouldn't use `Set` when you are dealing with values, `Set` is only used for `Object` type variables.

```
Sub YCheck()
  Dim CellCheck As Boolean

  If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Y" Then CellCheck = True
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = CellCheck
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim CellCheck As Boolean` CellCheck is instantiated as false. The elseif is redundant.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Sub YCheck()
    with Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B1").Value = cbool(ucase(.Range("A1").Value) = "Y")
    end with
End Sub
```